# Масть "перец с солью"

Tags: орфография

Масть животных и цвет волос человека, когда черные волосы чередуются с седыми, называют "перец с солью". А как правильно писать это название: в кавычках или без, через дефисы или раздельно.
Буду благодарен за ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чаще встречается в кавычках: щенки окраса "перец с солью",здесь словосочетание в условном значении, но можно и без кавычек, потому что это термин, можно сказать и так: волосы цвета перца с солью,а можно так: окрас "перец-соль" - на Ваш выбор.